# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reset') at SafeSubscriber._next

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a primeNg table in angular 13 , and when I run the command `this.dt.reset()` it gives me this error , and also checking the table import and everything ok what could be ?

```
@ViewChild("dt", { static: false }) public dt: Table;

updateItem(itemUpdated: Item, tableName: string) {

    const url = this.accountService.REST_API_SERVER_CALC + tableName + 's/' + itemUpdated.idForeign;
    // console.log('VehicleService - updateItem url=' + url);
    this.http.put<{ item: Item }>(url, itemUpdated)
      .subscribe(responseData => {
          if (responseData['Result'] === 'OK') {
            const helpItem = responseData['Item'];
            console.log('this.helpItem: ');
            console.log(helpItem);
            const itemIndex = this.items.findIndex(item => item.idItem === helpItem);
            this.items[itemIndex] = helpItem;
            this.selectedEditMode = undefined;
            
            this.items = [...this.items,helpItem];
            this.setItems(this.items);
            this.dt.reset()// problem is in this line
            this.toastr.success('Item  updated');
            console.log(' helpitem : '+ helpItem.name)

           
          }
        },
        error => {
          this.toastr.error(error.message);
          console.log('ERROR:');
          console.log(error);
          this.error.next(error.message);
        });

  }
```

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'reset')
> at SafeSubscriber._next (vehicle.service.ts:624:21)
> at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183:1)
> at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122:1)
> at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72:1)
> at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
> at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35:1)
> at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
> at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33:1)
> at FilterSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
> at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:70:1)

I would like my table once changed the items reloaded its content

Comment: describe your problem in details. we don't know where you call updateItem and we can see your dt variable in your html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dt` seems to be undefined.

Do you call this method on `ngOnInit` or via the constructor? Then maybe the initialization is too late.

What you can do to solve this is one of these two options:

1. change `dt.reset();` to `dt?.reset();`
2. Make sure `updateItem` is only called when `dt` is initialized

Note that `dt?.reset();` has a questionmark which checks if `dt` is `undefined` or `null` and doesn't execute `reset()` in that case.

Comment: thank you so much for your help , but I couldn’t understand the problem, and instead it was such a simple thing